# My Nether map got wiped?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a map, then I went into the Nether, and opened it. This made a map of the area in the Nether around me (as expected). I then left the nether, and expanded my map I just created (surrounded it with 8 pieces of paper in a crafting bench) in the overworld. When I pulled the map back out, it was completely blank.

I tried to fix it by switching it out and back in again, and by re-entering the nether, but it made no difference.

What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quitting to the title screen will reload the map.

Additionally, if you reload the world, without the map in your inventory, it will act as if you are not holding it - meaning it will not show your position or update as you move around. You will need to reload *with the map in your hands.* At any time if you do this, it will update the map properly, and act as normal

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too, luckily I was in creative going to the nether. I opened my map in the nether and it was completely glitchin out... anyways when you come back out of the nether portal, is it still saves the stuff from the nether, which then it will not see you once you are in the over world, and so when the game cannot sense you it will freak out-therefore your map will go blank... this is my assumption though. What happened with me is that I went back to the overworld and my map was still in the nether... but it did not go blank. I really think this is the answer to what happened so.... yeah